# How to add "x" close button onto upper right corner of uk-modal popup?

Tags: javascript, php, css, modal-dialog, popup

I'm trying to add small "x" close button into top right corner of uk-modal popup. How can i properly add its php code and css and maybe its javascript?

I've tried to add below 1, 2 codes into 3 code block:

1) First code i've added:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
```

2) Second code added:

```
<div id="my-id">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <button class="uk-modal-close-default" type="button" uk-close></button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="my-id">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <button class="uk-modal-close-outside" type="button" uk-close></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

3) To this code block of popup:

```
   <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
    <div class="uk-modal-header">
            <h2><?php echo esc_attr_e( $options['popuptitle'] ); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-modal-content"><?php echo stripslashes( $options['popuptext'] ); ?></div>
        <div class="uk-modal-footer">
            <button id="button1" type="button" class="uk-button uk-button-large uk-button-<?php echo esc_attr_e( $options['popupbutton1style'] ); ?><?php if( $options['popupbuttonoptions'] != 'button-1-redirect' ) echo ' uk-modal-close'; ?>"><?php echo esc_attr_e( $options['popupbutton1text'] ); ?></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expected to get the true place of "x" close button on popup, but it's not in proper position and also can't close the modal popup.

I expect to get it like in the image below:

How to fix?

[example x button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU9bR.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if that helps you :

```css
.close-button {
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.topright {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0
}
```

```html
<header style="background-color:#000;color:#fff;">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('YourModalBox').style.display='none'" class="close-button topright">&times;</span>
</header>
```

Don't forget to set "`YourModalBox`" to your Modal `id`, and apply it to the header of your modal box, so it goes inside the `<div>` and stay at the top-right corner.

A live example from the web application I'm still developing (note that it won't show properly because I'm not posting the whole `body` HTML, it'd bee too long and irrelevant to the value of the answer :

```js
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it 
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target == document.getElementById('mod_mec')) {
    document.getElementById('mod_mec').style.display = "none";
  }

  if (event.target == document.getElementById('mod_therm')) {
    document.getElementById('mod_therm').style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#btn_menu {
  background-color: #000;
}

#btn_menu:hover {
  animation-name: change;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    background-color: #000
  }
  top {
    background-color: #777
  }
}

#subs {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#subs:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: hovering;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes hovering {
  from {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  top {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/3/w3.css">
<div class="w3-row-padding">
  <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
    <div id="subs" class="w3-display-container" onclick="document.getElementById('mod_mec').style.display='block'">
      <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding">Mechanics</div>
      <img src="_img/sub_bg.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="w3-display-middle w3-light-grey w3-padding">
        V<sub>avg</sub> = &Delta;s &div; &Delta;t
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mod_mec" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-top w3-card-4">
      <header class="w3-container w3-black">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('mod_mec').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
        <h2>Choose a topic</h2>
      </header>

      <!-- VELOCITY -->
      <div class="w3-col l3 m6 w3-margin-bottom">
        <a href="velocity.html">
          <div id="subs" class="w3-display-container">
            <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-black w3-padding">Velocity</div>
            <img src="_img/sub_bg.jpg" alt="House" style="width:100%">
            <div class="w3-display-middle w3-light-grey w3-padding">
              V<sub>avg</sub> = &Delta;s &div; &Delta;t
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can i add css to the custom css of wordpress and to which place should i add the php code inside popup php code block?

Comment: Try adding a simpler code for closing the modal : `window.addEventListener("click", function(){document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "none";});` ... Try adding an `id` called `modal` to every modal box so when the window is clicked it'll close all modals with the id `modal`.

Comment: If clicking the "x" isn't working, make sure you're pointing out the event to the modal box itself

Comment: its working but it shows only upper part of site content after closing

Comment: Try changing from uk-modal to the w3-modal I provided from the example of my website, it's probably creating some issue with the code (also, w3css is more complete, since it is also responsive and has more styles in-build), see the source code here : https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css

Comment: Also, don't forget to link the file on the `<head`> of your site, W3.CSS has been my favorite Framework of styles because it's way easier to use and to learn, see it here : https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/

Comment: couldnt do it just removes the scroll this is surbma popup plugin